# Can't start node server with PM2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I need to run a node server with PM2 on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance when I run `pm2 start app.js` the node app starts but it does not listen on any port even though I set it to run on port 3000.
When I run `pm2 log` i get the following error in the logs:

```
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10) 
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32) 
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12) 
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3) 
    at Object.<anonymous>(/apps/lib/node-v7.0.0-linux-
x64/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:48:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:32) 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10) 
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32) 
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3) 
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:10) 
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:382:7) 
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:137:9) 
    at bootstrap_node.js:497:3
```

Comment: The actual error is somewhere higher up in the error log. I don't think anybody can tell you what's wrong by just looking at what you posted because it doesn't show what the error is.

Comment: find the exact error by using `pm2 logs <app-name>` --lines 100